# This screen saver has no options that you can set

Tags: windows, screensaver

I am trying to change the screensaver options, but I see the settings are disabled.

And when I click on the "Settings..." button I am getting the error "This screen saver has no options that you can set".

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Registry settings solved the issue.

Run Regedit.exe and go to:

`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Control Panel\Desktop`

Modify values of the following keys:

- ScreenSaveActive to enable/disable screensaver.
- ScreenSaverIsSecure to display logon screen.
- ScreenSaveTimeout to set timeout in seconds.

Sign out/sign in.